# Is there a with context or function decorator in bash?

Tags: bash

I use several small bash utility functions, which all start with "set -ux" and end with "set +xu". How can I avoid such repetition?

In python, I'd use a function decorator or with-context, but I don't yet have a good idea for bash.

Comment: If they're actually scripts, why do you need to end them with `set -ux`? They're not going to persist after the script execution, so just having that once at the start should be enough, at which point it's like a decorator or `with` line

Comment: @muru: so sorry, they are functions, will edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1. move the final `set +ex` into a `RETURN` trap, which will execute when the function returns by either reaching the end of the body or using the `return` keyword, and
2. use an alias to combine the trap and initial `set -ex` into a single command

For example, with the following file:

```
% cat foo.sh                                                    
shopt -s  expand_aliases

alias trace='trap "set +ex" RETURN; set -ex'

foo () {
    trace
    echo bar
    echo foo
}

foo
```

Running it with bash will show:

```
% bash foo.sh                                         
+ echo bar
bar
+ echo foo
foo
++ set +ex
```

If these functions are for your interactive usage, `shopt -s  expand_aliases` can be omitted, since aliases are enabled in an interactive bash by default.

Comment: Nice; would this work if `trace` was a function instead of an alias?

Comment: @Fravadona it would be tricky - we need to set the RETURN trap for the outer function. To avoid aliases, one way would be to enable [tracing of the function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions) (`delcare -tf foo`) so RETURN traps are inherited, and then just have a single global `trap '...' RETURN`. But then we're back to two lines per function, unless we enable tracing for multiple functions at once.

Comment: awesome, never heard of the trap command before, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmm... with zsh I get the following output: "undefined signal: RETURN". Any idea for zsh-compatibility?

Comment: @gebbissimo with zsh, I think [trapping `EXIT` in a function](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Trap-Functions) is equivalent to bash's `RETURN`: "Executed when the shell exits, or when the current function exits if defined inside a function. The value of $? at the start of execution is the exit status of the shell or the return status of the function exiting."